# Why Visual studio can not debug when multiple IE opened

Tags: asp.net, debugging

If i have multiple `IE` opened before i debug my application and when the application runs on `IE` and if i have a debug point in my application why it is not coming to debug the application. How can i resolve this

Comment: Is your breakpoint in ASP.NET code, or in client code like JavaScript?

Comment: Is your application running locally?

Comment: `@Mantorok` : Yes my application running in local

Comment: I would say that the debugger has to attach itself to a process in order to work correctly.  And since by default, VS spawns a new IE process when you debug, it's not smart enough to attach itself to an existing IE process.  At least out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is using the ASP.Net Web Server then your url will be something like *http://localhost:1234*, if this is the case then you could attach to the process from VS under Debug/Attach to Process....

If it's running under IIS (i.e. *http://localhost/myapp/*) then you would need to attach to the Worker Process which in IIS 5 I think is **aspnet_wp.exe** and in IIS 6/7 would be **w3wp.exe**, please note in IIS 6/7 if you have multiple apps running under different pools you will need to use the relevant w3wp.exe process as there may be more than 1, you can usually identify the correct one under the User Name field in the Available Processes grid.